# R postscript command (colormodel cmyk) not working?

Tags: r, postscript, eps, cmyk, imagemagick-identify

I'm producing an EPS image in R, with black (box and axes) and red (points).

```
postscript('test.eps',colormodel='cmyk')
plot(1:10,col='red')
dev.off()
```

Using ImageMagick's `identify`, shouldn't it be in CMYK color model, instead of sRGB?

```
$ identify test.eps 
test.eps PS 576x756 576x756+0+0 16-bit sRGB 9.83KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Comment: PostScript doesn't have an sRGB colour space (though it can be characterised using a suitably configured CIEBasedABC space), so I doubt the ImageMagick result. I suspect ImageMagick has rendered the EPS to an image and given you the colour model of that image. If you post the EPS somewhere I can tell you what colour model(s) its using, but I don't think this method is reliable.

Comment: @KenS Thanks! What method would you use? I can't post the image here, where do you suggest? I was trying sendspace.com, but it seems to ignore a 3.9 kB file...

Comment: Well I would normally use dropbox, or any similar service; anything will do that you can save a file to, I'd have expected sendspace to be OK. If all else fails you can send it to ken at spamcop dot net.

Comment: ImageMagick renders EPS to raster using Ghostscript. I created a solid red image in Photoshop and saved it as CMYK EPS and then used ImageMagick identify red.eps and it shows colorspace as CMYK. So perhaps it is your postscript command or a bad version of ImageMagick.

Comment: @KenS https://www.dropbox.com/s/dnhn80265qucoy1/test.eps But maybe you'll want to create your own file using R?

Comment: @fmw42 Cool! What's your ImageMagick's version? Mine is 6.9.7-4, on Debian 9. My R version is 3.6.1.

Comment: I was using IM 6.9.10.70 Q16 Mac OSX Sierra.

Comment: I have no clue about using R, so I looked at your file, it has 3 commands to set the color, all of them use setcmykcolor; 0 1 1 0 setcmykcolor, 0 0 0 1 setcmykcolor and 0 0 0 1 setcmykcolor. So that's 2 pure black and one red color. Definitely its not sRGB so its the IM report that's incorrect. If IM renders the EPS to an image and then tries to do colour identification on it then it can't tell you anything about the source EPS, the result will depend entirely on the devices used to render. Possibly IM can read the colour **comments** from a Photoshop EPS, these are not present in this EPS.

Answer (score 1):

Try identify -verbose test.eps and see the sRGB is due to ImageMagick using the ghostscript sRGB icc profile. That is how ImageMagick renders the eps for display purposes. The RGB is color on a black background like a computer while CMYK is color on a white background like paper. The identify program must be explaining the display of the eps instead of the source eps.
I don't have enough points to comment.